# How do you get data from a CSV and store it into a table object in C++

Tags: c++, database, csv

So basically I want to be able to open a CSV file and construct a Table object based on the data in this file.

This is an example of how the data looks in the CSV file:

```
year,category,winner,entity

INT,STRING,BOOL,STRING

2015,CHEF OF THE YEAR,FALSE,John Doe

2015,CHEF OF THE YEAR,FALSE,Bob Brown

2015,CHEF OF THE YEAR,TRUE, William Thorton

2015,CHEF OF THE YEAR,FALSE,Jacob Smith
```

The first line lists the names of all of the attributes in the table, while the second line lists the attribute types.

I'm thinking I'd have to implement a Table and Row class for this to work. What I'm confused by is what data structure to store a table with different column value attribute types, and how exactly the layout of said Table and Row classes would look like.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Are you trying to implement a generic table - any number of columns/types?

Comment: Im basically trying to implement a table based off the data in the CSV. So the number of columns depends on the the number of columns in the CSV, and the attribute types are based off the second line of the CSV (Ex. INT,STRING,BOOL,STRING). After implementing the table, I'd want to be able to query said table but for now I'm only worried on constructing the table.

Comment: You are probably looking for [`variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant).

Answer (score 1):

Ok I recommend you use https://github.com/vincentlaucsb/csv-parser

for your case you only should remove the row with types because c++ can not generate classes on the fly (all types should be known on the compile-time)

here an example for your case

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "csv-parser/single_include/csv.hpp"

using namespace csv;

bool string_to_bool(std::string state)
{
    if (state == "FALSE")
        return false;

    if (state == "TRUE")
        return true;

    throw std::runtime_error("incorrect input");
}

struct Data
{
    int year;
    std::string category;
    bool winner;
    std::string entity;
};

int main()
{
    CSVReader reader("...enter path to your file ... /data.csv");
    std::vector<Data> entities;

    for (auto& row : reader)
    {
        Data entity;
        entity.year = row["year"].get<int>();
        entity.winner = string_to_bool(row["winner"].get<std::string>());
        entity.category = row["category"].get<std::string>();
        entity.entity = row["entity"].get<std::string>();
        entities.push_back(entity);
    }
}
```

csv file

```
year,category,winner,entity

2015,CHEF OF THE YEAR,FALSE,John Doe

2015,CHEF OF THE YEAR,FALSE,Bob Brown

2015,CHEF OF THE YEAR,TRUE, William Thorton

2015,CHEF OF THE YEAR,FALSE,Jacob Smith
```

create CMakeLists.txt

for install parser simply perform

```
git clone https://github.com/vincentlaucsb/csv-parser.git
```

and add in the CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(project_name)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
add_subdirectory(csv-parser)

add_executable(project_name main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(project_name csv)
```

project hierarchy

```
 $ ll       
total 24
-rw-r--r--@  1 user  staff   192B Jan 26 12:14 CMakeLists.txt
drwxr-xr-x@  9 user  staff   288B Jan 26 12:14 cmake-build-debug
drwxr-xr-x  23 user  staff   736B Jan 26 11:18 csv-parser
-rw-r--r--   1 user  staff   191B Jan 26 11:54 data.csv
-rw-r--r--@  1 user  staff   871B Jan 26 12:02 main.cpp
```

Comment: Do you know of a way to do it without using a github library?

Comment: prepare custom CSV parser, but it adds additional complexity to the code and makes it a more bug-prone. Also. when you use a third-party library you can get an advantage from contribution from other developers and perform own contribution for bugfix and project improving.

Answer (score 0):

You were asking in a comment about a solution without using a library. You were asking for more (variant data types), but I first show a standard C++ approach.

I guess, you are already done, with your task. In case that you are still interested, I will give you more detailed explanation.

`````
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <regex>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

// the delimiter for the csv
const std::regex re(",");

// One DataRow from the csv file
struct DataRow {
    int year{};
    std::string category{};
    bool winner{};
    std::string entity{};

    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, DataRow& dr) {

        // Read one complete line
        if (std::string line{}; std::getline(is, line)) {

            // Split the string, containing the complete line into parts
            std::vector<std::string> part(std::sregex_token_iterator(line.begin(), line.end(), re, -1), {});

            // Convert into our local data / types
            if (4U == part.size()) {
                dr.year = std::stoi(part[0]);
                dr.category = part[1];
                dr.winner = (part[2] == "TRUE") ? true : false;
                dr.entity = part[3];
            }
        }
        return is;
    }

    // Simple data output
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const DataRow& dr) {
        return os << "\nYear:     " << dr.year << "\nCategory: " << dr.category << "\nWinner:   " << dr.winner << "\nEntity:   " << dr.entity << "\n";
    }
};

// This will hold all CSV data
struct CSV{
    std::vector<std::string> header{};
    std::vector<std::string> types{};
    std::vector<DataRow> data{};

    // Extractor
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, CSV& c) {
        if (std::string line{}; std::getline(is, line)) {

            // Read and parse header
            c.header.clear();
            std::copy(std::sregex_token_iterator(line.begin(), line.end(), re, -1), {}, std::back_inserter(c.header));

            if (std::getline(is, line)) {

                // Read and parse types
                c.types.clear();
                std::copy(std::sregex_token_iterator(line.begin(), line.end(), re, -1), {}, std::back_inserter(c.types));

                // Get all data. Read all lines and parse them
                c.data.clear();
                std::copy(std::istream_iterator<DataRow>(is), {}, std::back_inserter(c.data));
            }
        }
        return is;
    }

    // Make some nice output
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const CSV& c) {
        os << "Header: ";
        std::copy(c.header.begin(), c.header.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(os, "  "));
        os << "\nTypes:  ";
        std::copy(c.types.begin(), c.types.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(os, "  "));
        os << "\n\nData:\n";
        std::copy(c.data.begin(), c.data.end(), std::ostream_iterator<DataRow>(os, "  "));
        return os;

    }
};

std::istringstream csvFile{ R"(year,category,winner,entity
INT,STRING,BOOL,STRING
2015,CHEF OF THE YEAR,FALSE,John Doe
2015,CHEF OF THE YEAR,FALSE,Bob Brown
2015,CHEF OF THE YEAR,TRUE,William Thorton
2015,CHEF OF THE YEAR,FALSE,Jacob Smith)" };


int main() {

    // Define a variable of type CSV. This will hold all data
    CSV csv{};

    // Read from a file and put everything into our variable
    csvFile >> csv;

    // Show all contents of CSV on screen
    std::cout << csv;

    return 0;
}````
`````